# Compare validators: is preventing my action method from rendering the required view in asp.net mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, compare, data-annotations

I want to test how the `[compare]` validators works, so I added it to my validation class as follow:-

```
public class Question_Validation
{
   [Required(ErrorMessage = "D Description Field is required..")]
   **[Compare("SequenceOrder")]**
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "S Sequence order Field is required..")]
    public string SequenceOrder { get; set; }}
```

And I have the following post action method:-

```
    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Create(int assessmentid, Question q)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        { 
            q.CreatedBy = User.Identity.Name;
            Questions_Assessments qa = new Questions_Assessments();
            qa.AssessmentID = assessmentid;
            q.Questions_Assessments.Add(qa);
            elearningrepository.AddQuestion(q);
            elearningrepository.Save();
            return RedirectToAction("Details", "Assessments", 
                                    new  { id = assessmentid });
        }
        return View(q); 
    }
```

But when I try to create a new question the following error where returned:-

> The view 'Create' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:.......

But if i remove the  `[Compare("SequenceOrder")]` from the validation class then the action method will work without problems, so what might be the problem.?

Comment: If you remove the `Compare` does your action render the `Create` view? It won't unless the model is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure there is a `Create.cshtml` view somewhere? Because the `Compare` attribute could just be making your model invalid for some reason and only when your **model is not valid** the Create view is called.

Do you have the same result if you do or don't enter `Description` and `SequenceOrder` the same?

You could try:

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "D Description Field is required..")]
[Compare("Question_Validation.SequenceOrder")]
public string Description { get; set; }
```

Comment: if i tried ur above code then in this case the application will always raise the following error even if the Description and the SequenceOrder are similar; "'Description' and 'Question_Validation.SequenceOrder' do not match."

Comment: @johnG you've checked that you have a `Create.cshtml` in the right place? Without the additional `Question_Validation`, does it compare the properties correctly? Can you set a breakpoint at `if(Model.IsValid..` and check what the errors in there are?